# Are Hibernate's named queries perform better in comparison with the regular ones?

Tags: java, hibernate-5.x

Is there any performance benefit of using named  Hibernate queries over the regular ones?

*E.g., would the **(1)** be preferable to the **(2)** in terms of performance?*

1.:

```
Query namedQuery = session.getNamedQuery(queryName);
// ... 
return namedQuery.list();
```

2.:

```
Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
// ... 
return query.list();
```

Where the `queryString` is similar to the content of the query with the name `queryName`.

To narrow down the scope of performance term, I'd like to name the following aspects that reduction would be considered beneficial in terms of performance:

1. The time spent on query preparation (compilation, e.g.);
2. The time spent on the actual query execution in the database.

Although, in many cases the query preparation time is negligible, it can still be a bottleneck in certain circumstances, and I wonder whether named and regular queries are handled differently (e.g. have different caches) in Hibernate?

So extracting a regular query as a named one would actually reduce the preparation time.

Comment: both is the same

Comment: I see a close vote and I'd be glad to improve and clarify my question if I will be provided with the details of what a reader may find unclear.

Comment: NamedQueries are precompiled, which means they will be slightly faster. But parsing a query is usually considered a negligible overhead compared to the time required to fetch the data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180597/named-query-or-native-query-or-query-which-one-is-better-in-performance-point-of

Comment: Thank you, @VeselinDavidov! That is a relevant question, however its answers don't elaborate much on performance.  I'll clarify my question to emphasize what it focused on.